# Randomly generated keys added using posting API on AA.com web

Tags: api, post, http-headers

I am trying to develop an app to create mileage account grammatically. When I tried to post the data, it was not successful. Then I figured out that when I register on AA.com, it seems there were some randomly generated state keys were added as part of the post data. I was not able to figure out how those were generated. Any idea were did those data come from?

Here is an example:
X-6LdxA4pr-uniqueStateKey: A42pnjFlAQAA-TXJ0ZZ5ivAUYcE-mJuaUrqO_mcRLW65L3RHISVjzpOI3gnLAawUCfCucinBwH8AABszAAAAAA==
X-6LdxA4pr-b: johkjd
X-6LdxA4pr-c: A_SknjFlAQAAcnSutPBubo-I0acEViW7dRlkP_Y_ZFoZJ3mLilEUFc1KOwwbAawUCfD6K9uywH8AAOfvAAAAAA==
X-6LdxA4pr-d: 0
X-6LdxA4pr-a: prrk=IpJRRlnza=pL9-aEk68iTKaQgE=t_LWmHCJ=nOHtBQG1jbk1jb51Jln7iA8iPpQhPpJAQOnDo0VmdNnMbXk1MLpSMzbMBVF120h1b7a1_SuSTwESyCnoQOkDf0HSvGwtipZ=f=6mE=kqg21VcO11rGbcwb1gTUkdTQ53_62OgDU=h=hPmpi35dSPBwUA_UUP=DREBV8XfVv7_txWPp81=InSQO1=m7xM2-E1rfF7=o=hUIH4e=bLuqoPBQpB8lG1fpG=TF1UikWPBVo0yG2p9DxSj=6=E0atIDMN2dW2nr27XVlSu8GPLDcmkOHMFVJ=8rn1f=bSeuWUkpu3Jqk1mobqQrkVpdJMJrnLqr1Ea3iX2dKmBo6j8kxeTUTPxOn35ma=F3Bt0xpMyDiMFO5qTwpUyw=hBtn3j-d=IE=Urgk3LpI3vpa1BZbzAlG3iAM3rrwSEtG6F-WwP=k=TVl=J0dNglLOg